# How to get git to ignore binary files when applying smudge/clean filters?

Tags: git

How would I get git to ignore binary files when applying smudge/clean filters?

There are numerous files so they can't be individually ignored but perhaps based on extension in .git/info/attributes?

There may have been a way to do this with negative selectors but I dont seem to have it working

Classification as "binary" should be consistent with other *nix tools like diff and less

Comment: Can you modify your smudge/clean filters to ignore anything that you classify as a "binary" file?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore by file extension directly in any .gitignore file, using typical globbing patterns like `*.png`.

Comment: I still want the files to be versioned and kept in sync with the repository. The smudge/clean filters just need not be applied to them since they are binary and altering "whitespace" in them is nonsensical and modifies them in an undesired manner

Comment: This is not a solution since `.gitignore` causes the files to be ignored both for smudge and clean but also for checking into the repository.  arcyqwerty wants the files saved but does not want them worked on by smudge and clean (which why the down vote).